# UILocalNotification on repeat every one second

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I have been able to get my `iBeacon` app to push local notifications to the users while the app runs in background mode, but for some reason this notification keeps on repeating at every one second interval,

```
UILocalNotification *notice = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

         for (int i=0; i<=1; i++)
          {
            notice.alertBody = @"We just found some great deals in this location!";
            notice.alertAction = @"Open";

       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notice];


         notice.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.2];
        }
```

I just want this notification to be displayed only once to the user when they enter the region.

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<=1; i++)`??? Really?

Comment: You don't say how this code is tied in to your iBeacon callbacks.  If you have this in a ranging callback, then it will be displayed repeatedly.  If you have it in your monitoring callback, it should not be displayed endlessly.

Comment: Great Answer, Thank you DavidgYoung. I called this in my ranging callback because I set it up in a logic statement.

Answer (score 2):

iOS ranges every second, so it sounds like your code is in the `didRangeBeacons` method. You should instead move your `UILocalNotification` code to the `didEnterRegion` method.

Answer (score 0):

use `presentLocalNotificationNow`. it makes the notification displayed only once at that time when user enter the region.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notice];
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you seem to be scheduling two local notifications, because your `for` loop should run twice. It implies you are not seeing the repeat of the same notification but two different notifications fired at almost same time. I suggest you go through your logic once again.

The `repeatInterval` property of `UILocalNotification` object by default is set as 0 i.e. non-repeat. Hence, it is not the case of setting `repeatInterval` because you want it to be non-repeating.

Answer (score 0):

try this . . .

```
UILocalNotification *notice = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notice.alertBody = @"We just found some great deals in this location!";
notice.alertAction = @"Open";
notice.fireDate = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.2];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notice];
```